# Running a C++ app via a Debugger vs normal launch?

Tags: c++

I have a program which crashes randomly when it is launched "normally".  I'm fairly confident there are bugs buried in a giant library I'm using which are the cause of the issue (otherwise my implementation has failed to account for some mysterious detail for how to employ it). If I try to debug the program, I get nowhere because it never seems to crash when run that way!

What would be a *typical* explanation for this?

Here are some guesses I had: Does the debugger alter the timing of threads perhaps?  (Such that race conditions could be magically solved / hidden?)  If something is being done which produces "undefined" behavior, would the debugger vs a direct execution be an apples to oranges comparison?

I simply don't know enough about debuggers to understand how they alter the execution.

Comment: When you say _"...normally..."_ do you mean a release build, or is it still a debug build ?

Comment: A typical explanation is undefined behaviour in your own code. UB may or may not caused a crash. If it crashes, that's lucky.

Comment: The problem probably in the fact that you step through the program (or alter the execution in some other time-realted way), thus, eliminating some real run conditions. Also, if you use some sophisticated IDE, check for proper configurations for all types of builds. Generally, you still can narrow down the scope in which to search for bug(s) by using the debugger.

Comment: Sounds to me like a timing bug somewhere, where one component isn't waiting long enough for a return value when run in the standard way, but then that value is ready when debugging

Comment: I'm running a Release build through a Debugger.  *Without* setting any break points.

Comment: Note: A debug build has even more problems than release in this use case.  That's why I'm running this way. The third party library is jam packed with precompile directives that make the two builds more divergent than I've ever seen anyone write for those alternate contexts.

Comment: The debugger will still change the timing and may do nice things like null variables (to make spotting an uninitialized pointer easier--except for the times that it makes the null pointer check work) or set them to a distinctive pattern (to make overflow easier to detect-except when it doesn't).

Comment: Hmm.  A debugger may set pointers to null, which would be otherwise left in an undefined state?  That certainly could have major implications!